# Is it possible to rename imported library in android studio?

Tags: java, android

i have imported some  libraries to my project  in android studio
some libraries i want to rename it as i want.

Forexample
com.google.firebase:firebase-database
 i want to change it to com.google.anyname:anothername-database

**is it possible to rename it?** 
also in the head of class  rename

import com.google.firebase.database.Database;

change to 
import com.google.anyname .myname.databse